# Select the biggest value and print the line

Tags: sorting, sed, awk

I need some help with text manipulation.
I do have data like this:

> 29554 31109   "ENSG00000243485.1" 1555
>   29554   31097   "ENSG00000243485.1" 1543
>   29554   30039   "ENSG00000243485.1" 485
>   30564   30667   "ENSG00000243485.1" 103
>   30267   30667   "ENSG00000243485.1" 400
>   30976   31109   "ENSG00000243485.1" 133
>   89295   133566  "ENSG00000238009.2" 44271
>   89295   120932  "ENSG00000238009.2" 31637
>   120775  120932  "ENSG00000238009.2" 157
>   112700  112804  "ENSG00000238009.2" 104
>   92091   92240   "ENSG00000238009.2" 149
>   28269867    28269929    "ENSG00000248451.1" 62
>   28270383    28270486    "ENSG00000248451.1" 103
>   28273195    28273372    "ENSG00000248451.1" 177
>   28275308    28275354    "ENSG00000248451.1" 46
>   .....................

I have to print the line with the biggest value per group.
There is group name in column 4 and values are in column 5.
As I imagine it should go like this:
1. Separating groups from each other;
2. Selecting biggest value;
3. Printing the whole line.

Preferred output for the example should be:

> 29554  31109   "ENSG00000243485.1" 1555
>   89295   133566  "ENSG00000238009.2" 44271
>   28273195    28273372    "ENSG00000248451.1" 177

Hope someone could help me with this in awk or sed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do in `bash` and `awk`:

```
GROUPS=$(cut -d' ' -f3 datafile | uniq) # list of groups
for f in "$GROUPS"
do 
  # print line if 4th field is max
  awk -v "grp=$f" '$0 ~ grp && $4 > max {max=$4; line=$0} END {print line}' datafile
done
```

Comment: Pity but it don't work. I am getting the line with the biggest value printed. From my example it would be:  

"89295 133566 "ENSG00000238009.2" 44271", but not for every group separately.

Comment: the output is indeed for every group:
    29554 31109 "ENSG00000243485.1" 1555
    89295 133566 "ENSG00000238009.2" 44271
    28273195 28273372 "ENSG00000248451.1" 177

Comment: if you pass the group name with `-v`, you don't need to use double quotes and escaping tricks for the awk script: `awk -v "grp=$f" '$0 ~ grp && $4 > max {max=$4; line=$0} END {print line}'` -- an uninitialized variable is treated as zero in numeric context.

Comment: @glennjackman thx for feedback, your `awk` writing is better, I have edited the answer

Answer (score 2):

You only need to pass through the file once with awk:

```
awk '
    $4 > val[$3] {val[$3] = $4; line[$3] = $0} 
    END {for (grp in line) print line[grp]}
' filename
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
cat -n file | sort -k4,4 -k5,5nr | sort -u -k4,4 | sort -n | cut -f2-
```